# Showing the next post's title, even if it's an unpublished post

Tags: publish, next-post-link

At the bottom of each post I need to either:

- Offer a link to the next post (if the next post is published); or
- Display the title of the next post with the date it will be published (if it's a future post)

Suggestions?

Comment: You are trying to replace your post navigation with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add these two where you want them to display within your single.php file. It will make the title of the post a link.

```
<?php previous_post_link(); ?>
<?php next_post_link(); ?>
```

EDIT:
Sorry I missed the second part of your question about future posts. Here's what I would probably do. It's not tested, but will give you an idea.

```
$adjacent_post = get_adjacent_post(false,'',false) ;
if (get_post_status( $adjacent_post->ID ) == 'publish'){
    echo '<?php next_post_link(); ?>';
}
else {
    echo get_the_title($adjacent_post->ID).' | '. $adjacent_post->post_date;
}
```

Comment: Even if the next post is set for a future date?

Comment: Sorry, I had bypassed that part of your question. This will check if the next post is published, and if not, it will echo the name and the post date. You can modify however you want, but should give you the idea.